# PHP::How to call class method with params without eval()?

Tags: php, class

I have classname, methodname and I have an array with parameters. I want to do this call : "**$class->method($param1,$param2,..);**"

If i do It with eval(), I can't use get_called_class() function for PHP 5.2 (It can't find filename in eval code). **I need to call action widthout eval...** How to do it?

P.S. I don't know count of params, i need to send in method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method_name), $args);
```